# //@ sourceURL equivalent for CSS

Tags: css, debugging, firebug

In Firebug, [`//@ sourceURL`](http://blog.getfirebug.com/2009/08/11/give-your-eval-a-name-with-sourceurl/) can be used in a Javascript `eval`. We can use this technique to concatenate multiple Javascript files into a single file, and still have them show up as separate files in devtools/Firebug, like so:

```
eval("... foo.js contents ...\n//@ sourceURL=foo.js");
eval("... bar.js contents ...\n//@ sourceURL=bar.js");
```

Is there a similar technique for CSS files?

Answer (score 3):

In CSS the correct API is to use

```
/*# sourceMappingURL=<url> */
```

Previous proposed format seen bellow has not been adopted by all browsers

```
/*# sourceMap=<url> */
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in mobile Safari, and if there is any documentation on it, it keeps eluding me. Any idea if Safari supports this in some manner?

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of a better idea, it *might* also be possible to use [Sass sourcemaps](http://bricss.net/post/33788072565/using-sass-source-maps-in-webkit-inspector) to achieve something like this. It seems like a hack, but perhaps it's a start.

Thanks to Andy Matthews for the pointer.