# sourceURL for CSS

Tags: css, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

Is debugging `sourceURL` possible for CSS in Firefox?

The solutions listed in the following do not appear to work:

- [//@ sourceURL equivalent for CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15262506/sourceurl-equivalent-for-css)
- [Is there something like source maps for CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15818636/is-there-something-like-source-maps-for-css)

MDN in [Style Editor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Style_Editor#Source_map_support) states a possibility but it seems to be for *Sass*.

#### Update on reply

Using `sourceMappingURL` & `sourceURL` has some incomplete result:

- **Inspector** still shows file as `blob` ❎
  `blob:moz-extension://*****-****-******/*****-****-******`
- **Style Editor** lists file name ✅
- **Style Editor** fails to display file (since there is no real URL) ❎

```
Error while fetching an original source: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource. 
Source URL: moz-extension://*****-****-******/****.css
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a solution with `sourceURL`. I used an empty inline [source mapping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Use_a_source_map) as an alternative. "Empty" meaning that it does not contain any source changes, it just points at the source file.

The source mapping with `/*# sourceMappingURL={sourcemapurl} */` in Firefox will behave almost like `/*# sourceURL={url}*/` in Chrome.

It guess it depends on your use case if that is an option.

In my case the code looks like this (uses [magic-string](https://github.com/Rich-Harris/magic-string) for generating the source mapping):

```js
function addStyle (filename, css) {
  const sourceMap = new MagicString(css).generateMap({
    source: filename
  })

  css += '\n/*# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;base64,' + btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(sourceMap)))) + ' */'
  css += '\n/*# sourceURL=' + sourceMap.sources[0] + ' */'

  document.head.appendChild(document.createElement('style')).innerHTML = css
}


addStyle('https://cvzi.github.io/stackoverflow/65274147/mystyle.css', `body{
  font-family:sans-serif;
  color:black;
  background:green;
 }
body h1{
  color:white;
  size:15;
}
`)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/magic-string@0.25.7/dist/magic-string.umd.js"></script>

<h1>This is h1</h1>
```

Comment: Dev tools shows the CSS for be from a remote source that is actually valid source. Is there a way to show it for a local source?

Comment: You can use file:///to/your/local/source.css instead of a URL, then you can also edit the css files in dev tools.

Comment: There is no file. It is injected by the extension as a blob.

Comment: I see, I didn't think of that, I just use it like that for user script development, not for extensions. I believe you could use data urls, if you don't have actual files. Instead of source:filename use source:'data:text/css;base64,'+btoa(css) But then you would probably have the ugly base64 as a filename the dev tools